# Merge data using Integration Service

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, business-intelligence

Please Consider this scenario:

I have a table in my database. I want move this data in my OLAP database using SSIS.I can move all record from my table to OLAP database.The problem is I don't know how I can apply changes in OLAP environment.For example if just 100 record of my table were changed how I can apply this changes NOT copy all records from scratch.

How I can Merge this two tables?

thanks

Comment: How you consider data as changed: based on a datetime column in concerned table?

Comment: Is our OLAP database a relational database or a SSAS cube?

Comment: It's a rational database that I created my cube based on that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two main approaches to this:

- Lookup Transformation --> OLE DB Command / OLE DB Destination
- Load all data to a staging table and perform the MERGE using SQL.

My Preference is for the latter because the update is SET Based, but I do use the former where I know it will be predominantly inserts.

With the former you will end up with a data flow task something like:

[image]

This is a OLE DB Source from the OLTP database, which then looks up against your OLAP Database to retrieve the surrogate key. Where there is no match it simple inserts a new record to the OLE DB Destination, when there is a match it does a conditional split, if any fields have changed it will use the OLE DB Command to update the OLAP table.

It can obviously get much more complicated than this, but this covers the simplest example.

You can also use the Slowly Changing Dimension Transformation to open up a wizard to create your data flow for you, which again gets a bit more complex:

[image]

As mentioned though, my Preference is for a staging table and a set based update, because the OLE DB Command executes on a row by row basis, so if you are updating millions of records this will take a long time. You can simply create a staging table on your OLAP database and move the data in with a simple OLE DB Source and Destination, then use `MERGE` to update the OLAP Table:

```
MERGE OLAP o
USING Staging s
    ON o.BusinessKey = s.BusinessKey
    AND o.Type2SCD = s.Type2SCD     
    AND o.Active = 1
WHEN MATCHED AND o.Type1SCD != s.Type1SCD THEN 
    UPDATE
    SET Type1SCD = s.Type1SCD 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (BusinessKey, Type1SCD, Type2SCD, Active, EffectiveDate)
    VALUES (s.BusinessKey, s.Type1SCD, s.Type2SCD, 1, GETDATE())
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND o.Active = 1 THEN 
    UPDATE
    SET Active = 0;
```

The above assumes you have one active record per business Key, and both type 1 and type 2 slowly changing dimentions, it will insert a new record where there is no match on BusinessKey and Type2SCD, in addition it will set any unmatched records in the source table to inactive. When there is a match but the type 1 SCD is different this will be updated.

It is worth noting that [MERGE has it's downsides](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), and you may want to write your set based upserts as separate INSERT and UPDATE statements. One major issue I have come across is that on all my Dimension tables I have a unique filtered index on my `BusinessKey` field `WHERE Active = 1` to ensure there is only one active record, which the MERGE I have written should work fine for, but doesn't as detailed in [this connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/773895/merge-incorrectly-reports-unique-key-violations). Although it was not the end of the world having to add `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8790);` to the end of all the MERGE statements in my ETL it was not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're wanting to use incremental loads.

The first five tutorials [on this page](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/) should point you in the right direction - I found them really useful in the past.